# Unable to launch notebook as root

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run pyspark in Jupyter notebook as root user. I enabled root access for notebook by editing /root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py. I also edited bashrc file as mentioned in https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f under section Method 1 — Configure PySpark driver. However on trying to run pyspark as root I get

xdg-open: no method available for opening 'file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-20051-open.html'

```
# pyspark  
[I 17:12:15.544 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/applied  
[I 17:12:15.544 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:  
[I 17:12:15.544 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=c5408eb73daf9b0c7c3a92418b69e128d01b1c11a8ed8d75  
[I 17:12:15.544 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).  
[C 17:12:15.553 NotebookApp]   

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:  
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-20384-open.html  
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:  
        http://localhost:8888/?token=c5408eb73daf9b0c7c3a92418b69e128d01b1c11a8ed8d75  
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/applied/.Xauthority which is owned by applied.)  
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/run-mailcap line 528.  
[20515:20515:0612/171215.882932:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.  
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1  
Opening "/root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-20384-open.html" with Firefox Web Browser  (text/html)  
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/applied/.Xauthority which is owned by applied.)  
[20586:20586:0612/171216.094968:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.  
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/applied/.Xauthority which is owned by applied.)  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium-browser: not found  
[20614:20614:0612/171216.184980:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found  
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found  
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-20384-open.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after I upgraded my system.
The error specifies that Firefox should not be opened in root mode, but if `sudo` is not used, then `jupyter notebook` throws a *permission denied* error. I solved it—though I am not very satisfied by the solution myself—by changing the permissions of the following recursively:

```
~/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/*
```

So basically, I changed the permission of `.local`, then `./local/share`, and so on, all the way up to the contents of the runtime. Then, when I ran `jupyter notebook` (note, no `sudo` here) in the terminal, it worked.

There is yet another solution, though. As the terminal window says, you can manually copy and paste the URL specified into your preferred browser. But this will have to be done manually each time.

P.S. My system is a personal laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.